# Get Week Number of the year with custom day as starting day of the week

Tags: powerquery

I want to use Date.WeekOfYear() Function to get Week Number for datetime values, but with a custom day as the start of the week (Let's say Saturday rather than Sunday). How is it possible in PowerQuery M?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional statement like this (adding 1 to the weeknumber if the day is saturday):

```
if Date.DayOfWeek([Date])=5 then Date.WeekOfYear([Date])+1 else Date.WeekOfYear([Date])
```